# respuesta.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de obtener valores mediante un `json` el cual es un arreglo multidimensional

[image: respuesta json]

Dicho `json` estoy tratando de recorrerlo para obtener, por ejemplo, de **respuesta_resultado_banca_privada** obtener un campo llamado *BANCO* pero a la hora de obtener dicho campo me sale el siguiente error:

> respuesta.forEach is not a function

- **JSON**

```
resultado_banca_privada:

        0: {BANCO: "BBVA", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "25724452", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "2542452", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "15415156"....

        1: {BANCO: "SANTANDER", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "25424254", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "2542452", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "15415156"....
```

- **Código**

```
function table(respuesta)
{
    respuesta.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element.respuesta_banca_privada.BANCO);
    });
}
```

Comment: Según se ve, tu objeto no es un array realmente, por lo tanto no puedes usar `forEach` con él.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que un objeto no posee la función *forEach()* para que puedas recorrerlo ya que los elementos dentro del mismo poseen una clave y un valor. Si deseas algún dato dentro de objeto necesitas acceder a ellos mediante la clave del mismo.

La posible solución a tu caso seria recorrer cada elemento dentro del json cargando la clave a una variable dentro de un  *for()*:

```js
var dato = {
    0: {BANCO: "BBVA", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "25724452", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "2542452", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "15415156"},
    1: {BANCO: "SANTANDER", TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "25424254", TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "2542452", ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "15415156"}
        };


    for (var item in dato){
        console.log(dato[item].BANCO);
    }
```

Y luego accedes a la clave que necesitas(en tu caso, la propiedad *BANCO*). Suerte
Espero te sirva el ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Como te mencionaron es un objeto que no posee la función foreach
por lo tanto puedes recorrer el objeto por clave y valor teniendo en cuenta de que es multidimencional tienes que recorrer por llaves para este caso usas un for in 
que recorre primero respuesta_banca_privada y después accedes a las propiedades de la misma con otro for para mostrar los nombres hache te dejo un ejemplo

```js
var bancos = {
    resultado_banca_privada : {
      0 : {
            BANCO: "BBVA", 
            TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "25724452",    
            TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "2542452", 
            ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "15415156"
        },
      1 : {
            BANCO: "BBVA 2", 
            TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "33333",    
            TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "44444", 
            ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "7777"
        }
    },
    resultado_banca_publica : {
        0 : {
          BANCO: "SANTANDER", 
          TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "25424254", 
          TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "2542452", 
          ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "15415156"
        },
        2 : {
          BANCO: "SANTANDER 2", 
          TOTAL_ACTIVO_1: "77777", 
          TOTAL_ACTIVO_2: "8888", 
          ABSOLUTA_TOTAL_ACTIVO: "99999"
        }
        
    }
 };

for (var key in bancos){
   
    for ( keyBanco in bancos[key]  ) {
      console.log(bancos[key][keyBanco].BANCO )
    } 
}
```